# SUMIF with OR criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to use `SUMIF` formula in Excel cell that must sum over a given range and instead of finding for a single value, it should find multiple values?

For finding a single value, I use:

```
=SUMIF(A4:A100;"1";B4:B100)
```

Now I need to sum over if the column `A` holds `1` or `2`, like:

```
=SUMIF(A4:A100;"1" OR "2";B4:B100)
```

The cell `A1` will hold the criteria as a text, here it would be `1;2`.

It should return same as

```
=SUMIF(A4:A100;"1";B4:B100) + SUMIF(A4:A100;"2";B4:B100)
```

but I need a formula that can take any number of criteria (1,2,3,... or more).

What's the syntax? I'm not able to use VBA here.

Comment: You can use `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: Your immediate solution could be `=SUMIF(A4:A100;"1";B4:B100)+SUMIF(A4:A100;"2";B4:B100)`...

Comment: Yes it should return same as =SUMIF(A4:A100;"1";B4:B100) + SUMIF(A4:A100;"2";B4:B100), but I need a formula that can take any number of criterias (1,2,3,... or more). I do not want to rewrite the formula ever

Comment: @user2143213 Then, this is something that you should have put in your question from the start...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To sum for 1 or 2 try this version

`=SUM(SUMIF(A4:A100;{1;2};B4:B100))`

`SUMIF` will return an "array" of two results so you need `SUM` to sum that array for the total for 1 and 2

You can add as many numbers as you like e,g,

`=SUM(SUMIF(A4:A100;{1;2;3;4};B4:B100))`

or with numbers listed in a range like Z1:Z10

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A4:A100;Z1:Z10;B4:B100))`

Comment: Is it `;` or `,` in the formula?

Comment: @PankajJaju It is either one, depending on regional settings.

Comment: I'm in UK so I normally use comma separators but I used ; semi-colon because that was the separator used in the question - that would be the normal separator used in most of Europe (where comma is used as a decimal separator)

Comment: That was it what I was looking for =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A4:A100;Z1:Z10;B4:B100))

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work under **Google Spreadsheet** (takes only first number), although `=SUM({1;2;3})` works as expected. Any ideas how to solve this under GS? My case is `=SUM(SUMIF(E9:E20;{"U+";"U"};C9:C20))` and I can't use matches like `"U?"`, `"U*"` etc.

Comment: Also you can do this with sumifs/array formulas, multiple criteria and named ranges as the multiple matching keys eg:
`=SUM(SUMIFS(output_dump[Value],output_dump[property],"CashFlows", output_dump[colName],named_range_of_matches))`

Comment: @KrzysztofPrzygoda Encountered the same issue. Looks like it was answered here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92066/adding-and-or-logic-into-the-criteria-field-sumif

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do OR within a single statement like this. You can use SUMIFS for multiple conditions where all need to be true, but in this case you would just need to add together multiple SUMIF statements:

```
=SUMIF(A4:A100,"1",B4:B100)+SUMIF(A4:A100,"2",B4:B100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "1" and "2" are mutually exclusive:

```
=SUMIF(A4:A100,"1",B4:B100)+SUMIF(A4:A100,"2",B4:B100)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should define a range, let's say `keys` where you keep all values for which you want to sum. so in this range you keep 1 and 2 and can modyfy it whenever you want. then you add a flag column with formula `IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A4,keys,0)>0,1,0),0)` - now you have column in which 1 is for the values you want to sum.

Answer (score 0):

this works with multiple text evaluation

`=sumif(M4:M206,"Sat",O4:O206)+sumif(M4:M206,"Sun",O4:O206)` // add here more + + +