# Sum results matching array of values.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a number of strings with corresponding values. Given a set of keywords I want to return the sum of all the values where the rows string matches one of the given keywords.

I have made available an example workbook here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=73DBED9E450E4673!107&authkey=!ALLfOf0NyFxao-U&ithint=file%2cxlsx

I understand you can use INDEX and MATCH to match multiple values, however I have not got very far with this approach due to the fact i seem to be trying to compare one array with another array whereas the INDEX MATCH approach seems to take a finite, or fixed range of keywords for comparison.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you may have missed is that you can use wildcards when attempting to match a string to a cell.

Using the formula `=SUMIF(data!A:A;"*Alaska*";data!B:B)` I think I get the results you want for that one keyword. A slightly more general form of this formula would be `=SUMIF(Data!A:A;"*"&A3&"*";Data!B:B)`, assuming the state you want to test against is in cell A3.

If you want to test for several, I'd just add several `sumifs` on the form above together, unless you want to use a lot of criteria. If that is the case, you'll have to use an array formula, something on the form of `=SUM(SUMIF(data!A:A;{"*Alaska*";"*Alabama*"};data!B:B))` etc. A bit more on this in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21529080/4497791) I copied that solution from ;)

I don't think there is any way to include both wildcards and a range in the searchterms, but I could of course be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks eirikdaude, this is a lot closer to what i need. I have updated the example sheet to show your result: b).
The issue with this formula is that i cannot seem to get it to work when referencing the keywords rather than specifying them as strings. See result c)

Comment: You will have to enter the state names, including wildcards, for the states you want to check against inside the curly-braces (`{}`). Or you could use the formula Tom Sharpe suggests, which I think'll also work, but which may not be quite as easy to read. @webjames

Comment: I get the same answer (testing for Alabama) using both formulae. Could use =SUMIF(Data!A:A,"*"&A3&"*",Data!B:B) to make it slightly more general (should have "*" before and after & signs)?

Comment: @TomSharpe Yeah, that's a good idea. I'll incorporate it into my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course. I hadn't remembered you could use wildcards like that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an array formula version (F1):-

```
=SUM(Data!B$2:B$99999*(LEFT(Data!A$2:A$99999,LEN(A3))=A3))
```

OR (F2)

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(Data!B:B),Data!B:B,0)*(LEFT(Data!A:A,LEN(A3))=A3))
```

Must be entered in D3 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pulled down as required.

For a single-cell formula, this seems to work fine (F3):-

```
=SUM(Data!B2:B99999*(LEFT(Data!A2:A99999,LEN(TRANSPOSE(A3:A7)))=TRANSPOSE(A3:A7)))
```

OR (F4)

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(Data!B:B),Data!B:B)*(LEFT(Data!A:A,LEN(TRANSPOSE(A3:A7)))=TRANSPOSE(A3:A7)))
```

But be aware that if there is a blank cell in A3:A7, all the data will be selected and added to the individual totals. The second and fourth versions are slow.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - however that only sums the result for that single keyword 'A3' i need it to sum for keywords A3 to A7.

Comment: As mentioned by @erikdaude, you can sum individual totals, but if you really want to do it in a single formula you can try

=SUM(Data!B2:B99999*(LEFT(Data!A2:A99999,LEN(TRANSPOSE(A3:A7)))=TRANSPOSE(A3:A7)))

but I haven't time to test it properly at the moment.

Comment: Apologies - I missed the dollar signs out in my formula - have edited my answer.